# How to add new sample to CIFAR10 torchvision?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, dataset

Hi I want to add my own images to the CIFAR10 dataset in torchvision, how can I do that?

```
train_data = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=train_transform)
train_data.add # or a workaround!
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a custom dataset for `CIFAR10`, using the raw cifar10 images [here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html) or you can still use the `CIFAR10` dataset inside your new custom dataset and then add your logic in the `__getitem__()` method.
This is a simple example to get you going :

```py
class CIFAR10_2(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset_path='/cifar10', transformations=None, should_download=True):
        self.dataset_train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(dataset_path, download=should_download)
        self.transformations = transformations

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # do as you wish , add your logic here
        (img, label) = self.dataset_train[index]
        # for transformations for example
        if self.transformations is not None:
            return self.transformations(img), label
        return img, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset_train)
```

you can get fancy and add logic for test,validation, etc and do what ever you like.